# Do I even need to use oauth2 to manage a remote login? Is this just for api calls?

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth-2.0

For example, my goal is to authenticate the user and bypass the login form entirely, so ultimately they can click a link and login without touching the form. The code below gets me my access token...what are the next steps after that? Shouldn't I be authenticated and logged in so I can just redirect to what was a password protected page pre login/authentication?

Is it similar to the process of getting the authorization code? Passing the token information in the url? Can I do this with no login endpoint?

So it'd be https://api.thirdpartyservice.com/endpoint?access_token=123131414134314&token=bearer" - for example?

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
$code=$_GET['code'];
}

$post = array(
    "grant_type" => "password", 
    "username" => "username@example.com",
    "password" => "Pa55w0rd",
    "code" => $code, 
    "client_id" => "1234567-1234-1234-1234-123456789", 
    "client_secret" => "abcdefg-abcdefghijk-abcd-abcdef-abcdefghijklmo-abcd", 
    "redirect_uri" => "http://myapp.example.com/auth"
);

$postText = http_build_query($post);

$url = "https://api.thirdpartyservice.com/api/oauth2/token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postText); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result); 

?>
```

Comment: Or am I heading down the wrong path and the authorization code is not necessary if I have the ability to set a non expiring access token...arg...how do I use that token! Still looking; just noting the thought process.